# SQL Server Agent job fails once a week with 'Login failed for user ...\$duplicate-1889'

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I run a series of DTS packages via SQL Server (2000) Agent every night. They have been running ok for years until I added a couple of transform data tasks that pick up info from another local SQL Server (2008).

The odd thing is that the tasks run ok for about a week and then fail with the error 'Login failed for user domain\$duplicate-1889'. I don't run these packages using this user account, in fact I don't think it's a real account. I have a Windows account called dbadmin which has been set up on both servers to have access. This dbadmin account is used to start up the SQL Server Agent service and run the scheduled jobs.

When the jobs fail, all have to do to get them to run again is to stop and restart SQL Server Agent. But after a week they fail again with the same issue. Also, it's not the same day of the week each time.

I checked the Windows event log and although I can see the error, I can't figure out its cause. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `domain\$duplicate-1889` name looks like machine account. Every machine joined to a domain has such an account in the domain that the machine uses to authenticate to the domain.

The passwords for those accounts are automatically handled and the password is periodically changed automatically. By default that interval is [30 days](http://blog.joeware.net/2012/09/12/2590/) but if is changed to once a week in your environment maybe there's a problem when the computer's password has been updated?

It is possible to [disable the automatic changing](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc785826%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) maybe that's worth trying to see if the problem dissapears.

Comment: Thanks Anders, this sounds possible. I've changed the setting suggested, but it might take a week to see if it's worked.

Comment: I'm afraid the setting change didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I noticed the second job that fails is running an MS Access query and says 'ODBC connection to SQL server native client 10.0... Failed'. The error on the event viewer for both jobs is the same, 'Token based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error'.